# Equivalen norm on Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis

Let $||f||_{W^{1,p}}=(||f||^p_p+||g||^p_p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ and $||f||_{W^{1,p}}=(||f||_p+||g||_p)$ two norm on Sobolev space. I want to prove that are equivalent on this space. (g is the weak derivatives of f)

Given two norms $||.||_1$ and $||.||_2$ they are equivalent if exist two constant C and C' so that $C||.||_1\le||.||_2\le C'||.||_1$

I don'y know how  to find these constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't  positive constants $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that
$$
\forall x\ge 0\quad C_1x \le x^{1/p}\le C_2 x
$$
if $p>1$ (it is sufficient to draw the graph of the function $ x^{1/p}$).

---

The lines above are no more appropriate to the update question.

---

*Answer to the updated question.* The problem is to find $C_1$ and $C_2$ such that, for any $x,y\ge 0$ and $p\ge 1$
$$
C_1(x+y)\le (x^p+y^p)^{1/p}\le C_2(x+y),
$$
or
$$
C_1'(x+y)^p\le (x^p+y^p) \le C_2'(x+y)^p.
$$
Suppose, to fix ideas, $x\le y$. Then
$$
x^p+y^p\le 2 y^p\le 2(x+y)^p
$$
On the other hand, since $y\ge(x+y)/2 $
$$
x^p+y^p\ge y^p\ge [(x+y)/2]^p = 2^{-p}(x+y)^p
$$

Comment: I've corrected the text.There was an error on the first norm

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: x and y are the p-norm of the function?

Comment: yes, for shortness